# jQuery validator method working differently on mobile

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-validate

**Read EDIT 2 at bottom**
Original post:

I have this jQuery validator method to check for a valid YYYY-MM-DD date:

```
$.validator.addMethod("myDate", function(value, element){

    var validformat = /^\d\d\d\d\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
    return validformat.test(value);

}, "Please enter a valid YYYY-MM-DD date");
```

It works fine on my computer - returns false when expected and true when expected. However, on my Android phone it always returns false - the input always says "Please enter a valid YYYY-MM-DD date" even when the date is valid.

Do any regex methods such as `.test()` work differently on Android (and possibly other phones), or is this a jQuery Validator bug?

EDIT: I have tried changing `validformat.test(value)` to `value.match(validformat)` with the same result - works on computer, not on phone.

**EDIT 2:** Ok even commenting everything else out inside the method and typing `return true;` still yields the error on my phone. Definitely a jQuery validator problem. Need a workaround though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked on an Android 2.3 phone. It works perfectly.

Therefore, I blame it on Android 2.2 only. So here's my little fix:

```
$("#myform").validate({
...
    <?php
    //only print out the rule into the JS if it's not Android 2.2
    if(!strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Android 2.2"))
        print "myDate: true, \n";
    ?>
```

Annoying hacks :)

Comment: OK, there's another problem. It's now showing an error message "Please enter a valid date" which I never even defined... I think it's jQuery validator kicking in because it's an input `type="date"`. So I just applied that user agent rule to the entire `<script>` block containing the validation.

Comment: (I have PHP fallbacks to all my validation anyway incase JS is off. So Android 2.2 can rely on that)